# imagecopyresized() function does not change to mentioned dimensions but to 20 x 20 px

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I am using the following code to change the size but it changes the image dimension to fixed 20 x 20 pixels. Please help.

```
$url="database_images/".$row['post_id']."_image.jpg";
$width=300;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
$orig_width = imagesx($image);
$orig_height = imagesy($image);
// Calc the new height
$height = (($orig_height * $width) / $orig_width);
// Create new image to display
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// Create new image with changed dimensions
imagecopyresized($new_image, $image,
0, 0, 0, 0,
$width, $height,
$orig_width, $orig_height);
// Print image
imagejpeg($new_image,"temp.jpg");
echo '<img id="post_image_display" src="temp.jpg">';
```

Comment: Did you bother checking what numbers you're feeding into `imagecopyresized`?

Comment: yes. the new width and height are 300 and 300. yet the image displayed is of height 20 and width 20

Comment: you could be displaying a cached version. Since the url in the `<img>` tag hasn't changed, the browser isn't required to try and load a new one. you could use a cheap hack, like `<img src="temp.jpg?cachebuster=<?php echo time() ?>" />` to make it look like a new url each time.